# variable to call list value - python

Tags: python, list, variables

I need my game to run this:

```
def w_win(l,l2,check):
    line = l
    line2 = l2
    for x in range(4):
        if line[x] == line2[x]:
            if len(str(check+check)) == 1:
                line[x] = "  "+str(check+check)+" "
            if len(str(check+check)) == 2:
                line[x] = "  "+str(check+check)+""
            if len(str(check+check)) == 3:
                line[x] = " "+str(check+check)
            if len(str(check+check)) == 4:
                line[x] = str(check+check)
```

but then I get this:

```
if line[x] == line2[x]:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

and I'm calling with

```
for p in range(2,1025):

    first = w_win([" ","2","16"," "],[" ","2"," ","32"],p)
```

any help?

Comment: what is line and line2? how you're calling the function? Provide complete error message too

Comment: It seems `line` or `line2` is NoneType when you call this function, you'd better consider it.

Comment: In addition to above comments, for loop is missing the colon at the end

Comment: more wondering if there is a way to use a variable in list calling

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: weird every time I try to out in a variable for the value of the list it fails

Comment: Can you post the updated code?  If you try to access an attribute or call a method on something in this case (```line```, ```line2```) that has ```None``` you will get this error, but the program you posted is passing valid values, so please recheck the code.

Comment: that the exact code

Answer (score 0):

Your w_win function is missing the return statement which is required when you are assigning the function's value to the variable 'first'. In your case the variable first is initialized to Class of 'NoneType' because of missing return statement.

Comment: You're welcome. I am not able to reproduce the same error you are getting on both Python 2 and 3.